# GEE: hourly to daily evaporation ERA data

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I'm trying to aggregate hourly data from ERA5 land to daily data over a specific shapefile in GEE. In theory my code is working, however, the output gives the same amount of evaporation for the entire time series.

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/014c446c0d21091096cf603de7b9df87

Note: I split the data into monthly subsets because GEE gave errors when I was trying bigger subsets.

EDIT the orginal code:

```
// prepare geometries
var basin = basin.first().geometry();
var watershed = watershed.first().geometry();
var water = [ee.Feature(basin, {'label': 'basin'}),
          ee.Feature(watershed, {'label': 'watershed'})];
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(water);

// prepare time dimension and main data source
var startDate = ee.Date('1989-11-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2021-01-01');
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
              .filterBounds(basin)
              .select('total_evaporation');
// split into smaller time ranges
var startDate1 = ee.Date('1990-01-01');
var endDate1 = ee.Date('1990-03-01');
var era5Collection1 = collection.filterDate(startDate1, endDate1);

// aggregate imagecollection to daily data
//var numberOfDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var numberOfDays1 = endDate1.difference(startDate1, 'days');

var daily1 = ee.ImageCollection(
              ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays1.subtract(1))
             .map(function (dayOffset) {
    var start = startDate1.advance(dayOffset, 'days');
    var end = start.advance(1, 'days');
    return era5Collection1
       .filterDate(startDate1, endDate1)
       .sum()
       .set('system:time_start', start.millis());
      })
);

var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(daily1, features, 
ee.Reducer.sum(), 'total_evaporation', 200, 'system:time_start', 
'label')
          .setChartType('ScatterChart');
print(chart1);
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Links tend to break and with it also the usefullness of questions (and answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the wrong variables in line 77

```
var daily1 = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays1.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate1.advance(dayOffset, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days');
      return era5Collection1
        .filterDate(startDate1, endDate1)
        .sum()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis());
    })
);
```

`.fiterDate(startDate1, endDate1)` should be `.fiterDate(start, end)`